# Would doubling speed of CPU allow system to handle twice as many processes?

Tags: cpu-speed, multiple-processes

If the speed of the CPU is doubled, would the system be able to handle twice as many processes? Assuming you ignore context switches that is.

Comment: I don't think speeding it up could handle more processes because your still limited by how much memory you have for them. But they would execute faster and threading would be faster for the processes you have memory for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. CPU speed is rarely the bottleneck anymore. Also, doubling the clock speed would require changers in both your OS's scheduler and your compiler (both of which make assumptions about the speed of a CPU relative to the data buses).

It would make things better, but it's not a linear improvement.